# problem with declaring with static keyword

Tags: c++, static

I have a function which converts a binary tree to doubly linked list. In the code I have used static keyword for simplicity. But the problem is that for multiple test cases it is not working fine and giving output for the 1st test case only. I can do the question in other ways to but I am curious to know how to do it for multiple test cases using the static pointer.

```
void bToDLL(Node *root, Node **head_ref)
{

    if(root == NULL)return;
    static Node* prev = NULL;

    bToDLL(root->left,head_ref);

    if(prev == NULL)*head_ref = root;
    else {root->left = prev,prev->right = root;}
    prev=root;

    bToDLL(root->right,head_ref);


}
```

### for the following

```
2 (test cases)
2  (edges)
1 2 R 1 3 L
4  (edges)
10 20 L 10 30 R 20 40 L 20 60 R 
expected:
2 1 3
30 10 60 20 40
output 
2 1 3
```

Comment: Don't use static variables. They rarely provide simplicity.

Comment: I doubt there any way to do this with a static variable that is simpler than not using a static variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your "prev" pointer to NULL between the two tests. Even though it's inside a function, the static variable will be initialized ONLY ONCE per program run! If you insist on the static approach, then put the declaration **outside** the function and reset it to NULL between tests (otherwise, it starts with the last value from the previous test). Better, though would be to have "prev" as an extra argument to the function, where it's passed as NULL in the 'top-level' call.